# create billboard slideshow with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, callback, slideshow

i saw a tutorial in [tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/16/creating-a-rotating-billboard-system-with-jquery-and-css/) and i did some changes to look more like a billboard but something is wrong and i don't know what it is! and it's really makes me crazy that where the hell is problem!
the first time that you run it's exactly that i want but when time passes it's getting ugly!i did this modification:

```
$(function() {
$('#ad_1 > img').each(function(i,e){
    rotate($(this),500,3000,i);
});
function rotate(elem1,speed,timeout,i){
    elem1.animate({'marginLeft':'18px','width':'0px'},speed,function(){
        var other;
        if(elem1.parent().attr('id') == 'ad_1')
            other = $('#ad_2').children('img').eq(i);
        else
            other = $('#ad_1').children('img').eq(i);
            other.animate({'marginLeft':'0px','width':'35px'},speed,function(){
            var f = function() { rotate(other,speed,timeout,i) };
            setTimeout(f,timeout+i*100);
        });
    });
}});
```

all the rest is just like the [tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/16/creating-a-rotating-billboard-system-with-jquery-and-css/)
thank you!!

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had stated that you had altered the `setTimeout` line from what it was in the tutorial. What were you hoping to achieve with your modification?

Comment: like the first time slide run.like i said before first time you run page and the way slide changes is that i want but when time passes it's getting bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future it will be helpful for you to describe *what* you are hoping to achieve rather than leaving it to the people of whom you are asking for help to figure it out for themselves. With some fiddling, I determined that what you want is, instead of each panel animating at the same time, a slight delay of the animations from left to right, so that each panel begins animating *after* its left neighbor has begun its animation.

You attempted to achieve this by adding an increment to the duration *between* a panel's rotations. The increment, computed as a function of the panel's index, is larger for higher indexes. The problem with this approach is that each panel spends a different duration of time in its display state - so as time goes on, the whole image becomes increasingly mangled.

The panels all need to have the same display duration, so revert your change to the `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(f, timeout);
```

What you actually want to do is to delay when each panel *starts* rotating. This can be achieved by adding a `setTimeout` in the `each` handler that initiates the rotations:

```
$('#ad_1 > img').each(function (i, e) {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
        rotate($(this), 500, 7000, i);
    }, this), (i * 100));
});
```

You will notice that I have increased the `timeout` value passed to `rotate` because more time will be required to accommodate the sequential animations.

I would also recommend that you put some effort into better formatting your code. Your sample, due to poor indentation, lack of spacing, and omitted curly braces, makes reading it a chore.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your answer.in my question I said when page run the first slide is exactly what I want but when time passes it's getting really bad

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without looking at the rest of the code, but your else statement is missing brackets. I think you meant to do this:

```
$(function() {
$('#ad_1 > img').each(function(i,e){
    rotate($(this),500,3000,i);
});
function rotate(elem1,speed,timeout,i){
    elem1.animate({'marginLeft':'18px','width':'0px'},speed,function(){
        var other;
        if(elem1.parent().attr('id') == 'ad_1') {
            other = $('#ad_2').children('img').eq(i);
        } else {
            other = $('#ad_1').children('img').eq(i);
            other.animate({'marginLeft':'0px','width':'35px'},speed,function(){
            var f = function() { rotate(other,speed,timeout,i) };
            setTimeout(f,timeout+i*100);
        });
       }
    });
}});
```

*edit: Did you remember to include jQuery?

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but there is no rest of code that's all!the HTML and CSS are the exactly files in original tutorial and else doesn't have bracket because the code for if and else here are just one line that you know you can do it without the bracket

Comment: added more to answer, see if that works for you. If your code is the exact same, then you need to make sure you're including the correct files (i.e. jquery) in the correct directory

Comment: ok look i don't have a syntax problem i know that and i said that when you run the page first slide goes perfect but when time passes it's getting bad you know it's just like i have symantic problem that i don't know what it is